# How to work with wildcards in Drools spreadsheet decision tables?

Tags: drools

I'm using Drools spreadsheet decision tables. I would like to implement rules with wildcards like:

- Input: A152
- Condition: string **matches** ($param)
- Rule: "A100","A200","A15*"

A second thing would be having a default rule like: if else fails ("*")

Do you know if that's possible - and if so: how? ;)

Comment: Avoid using drool, and make your custom decision processor. I have been in the same place, and I regretted it later on using it.

Comment: Drools is fine but decision tables are awful (slow, bloated).  Set your default rule to have higher salience so that it fires first, then let your other rules overwrite the default value if applicable.

Comment: Also what exactly is your question? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the rule you proposed (except you shouldn't need `()` around the $param.